# How to use Objective-C category in Swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-category

I have an Objective-C project, there is a file named 'NSDictionary+Test', and a method named `- (void)testDone:(TestBlock)block` in the file. I add a swift file to the project , how can i use  `- (void)testDone:(TestBlock)block` in my Swift file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly you have your Objective C proj and in it you have your category(in Obj C) and now you added a Swift file and want to use category method in Swift.

So now answer goes-

1. Firstly add your .swift file and mostly it asks for creating a bridging header. If it does not get created, follow the steps from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161114103929/http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/).
2. Add `#import "NSDictionary+Test.h"` before `#endif`.
3. Now you should be able to use the `(void)testDone:(TestBlock)block` as `dictionary.testDone(block : TestBlock!)`.